# no page numbers in lyx

Tags: lyx, page-numbering

How can I tell LyX to put page numbers in the rendered PDF?

I looked in all the menus, and haven't find the correct option.

The closest matches are: Document -> Settings -> Page Layout, or Document -> Settings -> Numbering, but none of them has page numbering.

--

Here is my first try to post a MWE:

```
#LyX 2.0 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article_acl_singlecolumn
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\float_placement h
\paperfontsize 11
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize a4paper
\use_geometry true
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine natbib_authoryear
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle fancy
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes true
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
No Page Numbers Example
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Can you please post a MWE (minimum working example) `.lyx` file?

Comment: Not sure how to do it, but I tried - I left only the title

Comment: I don't have your document class so I can't work with this. Everything works fine if you change your document class to `Article (Standard Class)` in Document > Settings > Document Class. I imagine that this is not what you want though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend of the document class that you have selected (by default is `article`) in `Document` > `Configuration`. Make a new simple document (only with some words) and make the PDF: the number of is showed by default centered at the footer. If you change the document class to `book` the number of page  will be in the top right in a beamer class is not showed ... and so on.

I do not have your document class but I changed this in your file:

```
\textclass article_acl_singlecolumn
```

by

```
\textclass article
```

to have the standard class `article`, and it show the number of page without problem.

Moreover, this can be modified by header and footer settings in Page layout or wih LateX code in the preamble. To understand how this work, read about the `fancyhdr` LaTeX package.

In any case, you can insert the number of page also in any part of the body document inserting a ERT box (Ctrl+L) with the code `\thepage`.

Answer (score 4):

```
Document -> Settings -> Page Layout -> Pagestyle
```

should *not* be set to `empty` amd there should also not a `\pagestyle{empty}` in your preamble.

Comment: In Document -> Settings -> Page Layout, I don't have pagestyle. I only have Format (which I set to "A4"), Orientation (which I set to "Portrait"), Heading style (which I set to "plain"), and Two-sided document checkbox (which is unchecked).

Comment: About the preamble - how do I see it?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble

Comment: "Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble" shows an empty box.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: It is the lower field in the page layout setting, not the upper one for paper size.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind... here is the dialog box: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-mMfXyy8lylX0N5TmJoRkc1UDQ/edit

Comment: ok it's called heading style. Change `fancy` to `normal` and looks what happens

Comment: I changed and it didn't help...

Comment: write into the preamble `\usepackage{layout}` and in the dcoument hit `Ctrl-L` and insert `\layout`. Then run LyX and look into the pdf, it shows the margin setting of the choosed layout. You'll see if the pagenumber maybe outside the paper size